# How to group data with SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, entity-attribute-value, amazon-timestream

How do I group my Timestream data?

The table looks simplified like this:

```
point_delivery_number | measure_name  | time                   | value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
AT3265345345          | "consumption" | 2021-01-02 12:00:00.00 | 0.13
AT3265345345          | "generation"  | 2021-01-02 12:00:00.00 | 0.32
```

I want to query where `point_delivery_number` == xx and `time` = xx

Result should be:

```
point_delivery_number | consumption | time  | generation
----------------------------------------------------------
AT3265345345          |  0.13       | xxxxx | 0.32
```

What I tried is:

```sql
    SELECT point_delivery_number, measure_name, time, measure_value::double 
    FROM "energy_datapoints"."energy_data"
    WHERE point_delivery_number='AT234123234541243'
    GROUP BY point_delivery_number, measure_name, time, measure_value::double;
```

Result is:

```
point_delivery_number | measure_name  | time                   | value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
AT3265345345          | "generation" | 2021-01-02 12:15:00.00  | 0.123
AT3265345345          | "generation"  | 2021-01-02 12:00:00.00 | 0.32
```

I want `consumption` and `generation` to be a property rather than a value.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What is the problem with the query you tried? It doesn't seem complicated unless I'm missing something...

Comment: More details, What comes out  from your current query ?

Comment: You appear to have an **EAV** data model; You'll need to *pivot*.

Comment: @wildplasser i am sorry, but i just jumped into the SQL world. Could you explain it a bit more or do you know how to construct such query?

Comment: SO is not intended for teaching. I added some tags / search terms. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a key/value table. Per point_delivery_number it has rows with a key (measure_name) and values (time and value).

You want to get the values for two keys. One way is to select both and join them:

```
select
  point_delivery_number,
  c.value as consumption,
  g.value as generation
from 
  (select * from energy_datapoints.energy_data where measure_name = 'consumption') c
full outer join
  (select * from energy_datapoints.energy_data where measure_name = 'generation') g
    using (point_delivery_number)
order by point_delivery_number;
```

Another way is aggregation. You want one row per point_delivery_number, so you `GROUP BY point_delivery_number`. Then use `MIN` or `MAX` on a condition to only get the measure names in question.

```
select
  point_delivery_number,
  min(case when measure_name = 'consumption' then value end) as consumption,
  min(case when measure_name = 'generation' then value end) as generation
from energy_datapoints.energy_data
group by point_delivery_number
order by point_delivery_number;
```

Disclaimer: I don't know Amazon Timestream. The above queries are standard SQL queries that should work (exactly as written or with slight changes) in most RDBMS.

As to your own query: You make it look like you are aggregating, but it seems you are simply selecting single rows, because your `GROUP BY` clause includes all columns. `GROUP BY ____` means "I want to aggregate my data to get one result row per ____". You want one result row per point_delivery_number, so `GROUP BY point_delivery_number`.